# Mostrar informacion de alimentos en java

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Hice un programa que tiene como finalidad la gestión alimentaria, aplicando herencia. Tengo tres tipos de alimentos que son subclases:

```
1.- Alimentos congelados
2.- Alimentos Refrigererados
3.- Alimentos Frescos
```

Cada una lleva atributos propios y extienden de mi clase padre, `Producto`, 2 atributos, los cuales son `Fecha de caducidad` y `numero de lote`.

Finalmente, tengo una última subclase, `TesHerencia3`, que está destinada para testeo porque así me lo solicitan y es la que hace que todos los datos se muestren por pantalla. Esta última subclase no hereda, si no que es mi clase `Main`, y los datos se muestran bajo consola al ejecutar.

Lo que busco hacer es exactamente lo mismo, pero ya no bajo consola, si no que en un `JFrame`, es decir, que cuando le de clic a un botón, muestre la misma respuesta de consola, pero en un `TextBox` o `TextArea`.

He estado tratando envanamente de conseguirlo pero, simplemente, no logro conseguirlo.

Clase TestHerencia, donde creo los objetos de tipo producto y donde posteriormente imprimo:

```
public class TestHerencia3 {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        ProductoCongelado nuggets = new ProductoCongelado("16-10-2016","L1603004");
        ProductoFresco lechuga = new ProductoFresco("20-10-2016","L1610005");
        ProductoRefrigerado jugo = new ProductoRefrigerado("25-10-2016","L1609006");
        nuggets.setTemperaturaRecomendada(-18);
        lechuga.setFechaEnvasado("03-10-2015");
        lechuga.setPaisDeOrigen("Panamá");
        jugo.setCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria("B#6745");
        System.out.println("Producto Congelado: ");
        nuggets.imprimirDatos();
        System.out.println("Producto Fresco: ");
        lechuga.imprimirDatos();
        System.out.println("Producto Refrigerado: ");
        jugo.imprimirDatos();
    }
```

Clase Padre:

```
 public class Producto {
String fechaCaducidad, numeroLote;
String PaisdeOrigen;

public Producto(String fechaCaducidad, String numeroLote, String PaisdeOrigen){
    this.fechaCaducidad = fechaCaducidad;
    this.numeroLote = numeroLote;
    this.PaisdeOrigen= PaisdeOrigen;
}

public void setFechaCaducidad(String fecha){
    fechaCaducidad = fecha;
}

public void setNumeroLote(String num){
    numeroLote = num;
}

public void setPaisdeOrigen(String PaisdeOrigen) {
    this.PaisdeOrigen = PaisdeOrigen;
}

public String getPaisdeOrigen() {
    return PaisdeOrigen;
}



public String getFechaCaducidad(){
    return fechaCaducidad;
}

public String getNumeroLote(){
    return numeroLote;
}

public void imprimirInfo(){
    System.out.println("Fecha Caducidad: " + getFechaCaducidad() + "\nNumero de Lote: " + getNumeroLote()+ "\nPaís de Orígen: "+ getPaisdeOrigen());
}
```

Clase producto:

```
public class ProductoFresco extends Producto{

private String fechaEnvasado;

public ProductoFresco(String fechaCaducidad, String numeroLote, String PaisdeOrigen){
    super(fechaCaducidad, numeroLote, PaisdeOrigen);
    fechaEnvasado = "Desconocido";     
}

public void setFechaEnvasado(String fecha){
    fechaEnvasado = fecha;
}


public String getFechaEnvasado(){
    return fechaEnvasado;
}


public void imprimirDatos(){
    imprimirInfo();
    System.out.println("Fecha de envasado: " + getFechaEnvasado() + "\n");
}
```

clase producto refrigerado:

```
public class ProductoRefrigerado extends Producto {

private String codigoSupervisionAlimentaria;
private String FechadeEnvasado;
private String TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada;


public ProductoRefrigerado(String fechaCaducidad, String numeroLote, String PaisdeOrigen){
    super(fechaCaducidad, numeroLote, PaisdeOrigen);
    codigoSupervisionAlimentaria = "Desconocido";
    FechadeEnvasado= " ";
    TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada=" ";
}

public void setCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria(String codigo){
    codigoSupervisionAlimentaria = codigo;
}

public void setFechadeEnvasado(String FechadeEnvasado) {
    this.FechadeEnvasado = FechadeEnvasado;
}

public void setTemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada(String TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada) {
    this.TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada = TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada;
}

public String getFechadeEnvasado() {
    return FechadeEnvasado;
}

public String getTemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada() {
    return TemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada;
}



public String getCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria(){
    return codigoSupervisionAlimentaria;
}

public void imprimirDatos(){
    imprimirInfo();
    System.out.println("Codigo de Supervision Alimentaria: " + getCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria()+ "\nFecha de envasado: "+getFechadeEnvasado()+"\nTemperatura de mantenimiento recomendada: "+getTemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada());
}
```

clase producto congelado:

```
    public void imprimirDatosAire(){
    imprimirInfo();
    System.out.println("Temperatura Recomendada: " + getTemperaturaRecomendada());
    System.out.println("Producto Envasado :" + getProductoEnvasado());
    System.out.println("COMPOSICIÓN DEL AIRE");
    System.out.println("-Porcentaje de Nitrogeno: " + getPorcentajeNitrogeno() + "\n");
    System.out.println("-Porcentaje de Oxigeno: "+ getPorcentajeOxigeno() + "\n");
    System.out.println("-Porcentaje de Dioxido de Carbono: " + getPorcentajeDioxidoCarbono() + "\n");
    System.out.println("-Porcentaje de Vapor de Agua: " + getVaporAgua() + "\n");
}

public void imprimirDatosAgua(){
    imprimirInfo();
    System.out.println("Temperatura Recomendada: " + getTemperaturaRecomendada());
    System.out.println("Producto Envasado :" + getProductoEnvasado() + "\n");
    System.out.println("Informacion adicional (salinidad)");
    System.out.println("-Salinidad del Agua: " + getSalinidadAgua() + "gr (NaCl)/1L H2O" + "\n");
}

public void imprimirDatosNitrogeno(){
    imprimirInfo();
    System.out.println("Temperatura Recomendada: " + getTemperaturaRecomendada());
    System.out.println("Producto Envasado :" + getProductoEnvasado());
             System.out.println("CONGELACION POR NITROGENO: ");
    System.out.println("-Metodo de congelacion Empleado: " + getMetodoCongelacionEmpleado() + "\n");
    System.out.println("-Tiempo de exposición al Nitrogeno: "+ getTiempoExposicionNitrogeno() + "\n");
}
```

Si es necesario todas las clases, me lo hacen saber.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes hecho sobre un `JFrame` hasta ahora?

Comment: Pues pense que podria instaciar mi clase TestHerencia3 dentro del JFrame, y luego llamar a mi clase Main, pero no es posible, ya que que TestHerencia3 es mi Clase principal, y por ende para hacerlo, primero dicha clase debe dejar de ser mi principal y no ser de tipo Static(segun yo) pero esa parte es la que no entiendo y no se como realizarla...

Comment: Probe muchas maneras, pero no llegue a nada, borre todo lo que tenia, ya que nunca me funciono...

Comment: Las preguntas en SO se resuelven sobre el código. Comparte lo que intentaste y sobre eso las personas pueden sugerir mejoras y cambios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudieras crear un OutputStream para redireccionar System.out o System.err. Pero no creo que sea buena idea que tus objetos impriman a la consola del sistema. Porque creo que esas consolas sirven a los programadores pero no al usuario final.

Yo cambiaría los métodos que te arrojan la información "imprmieDatos()", por String dameDatos();  Así en lugar de imprimir los datos te los dan.

Si ya cambias esos métodos, entonces puedes imprimir tu resultado tanto en la consola, si estás revisando, o en un componente swing, si lo quieres ver ahí.

Por ejemplo:

```
 String datos = new TestHerancia3().dameDatos();

 System.out.println("resultado="+datos);

 JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
 area.append(datos);
```

EDICIÓN: Agrego los métodos dameDatos() de un par de clases. Lo voy a hacer con tus mismos métodos, pero sugiero leas de la clase java.lang.StringBuilder que sirve para crear cadenas.

De la clase Producto:

```
    public String dameDatos() {
        return "Fecha Caducidad: " + getFechaCaducidad() + "\nNumero de Lote: " + getNumeroLote()+ "\nPaís de Orígen: "+ getPaisdeOrigen();
```

}

De la clase ProductoRefrigerado:

```
@Override
public String dameDatos() {
    return super.dameDatos() + //aquí estamos agregando los datos de clase Producto, y luego lo de esta:
    "Codigo de Supervision Alimentaria: " + getCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria()+ "\nFecha de envasado: "+getFechadeEnvasado()+"\nTemperatura de mantenimiento recomendada: "+getTemperaturaMatenimientoRecomendada();
}
```

Vamos a modificar la clase TestHerencia3 para que muestre los datos en una pantalla:

```
public class TestHerencia3 {

/**
  Vamos a usar este método para mostrar la info en un componente JTextArea
**/
static void dameDatos(javax.swing.JTextArea area) {

    ProductoCongelado nuggets = new ProductoCongelado("16-10-2016","L1603004","pais2");
    ProductoFresco lechuga = new ProductoFresco("20-10-2016","L1610005","pais3");
    ProductoRefrigerado jugo = new ProductoRefrigerado("25-10-2016","L1609006","pais4");
    nuggets.setTemperaturaRecomendada(-18);
    lechuga.setFechaEnvasado("03-10-2015");
    lechuga.setPaisdeOrigen("Panamá");
    jugo.setCodigoSupervisionAlimentaria("B#6745");
    System.out.println("Producto Congelado: ");
    nuggets.imprimirDatos();
    System.out.println("Producto Fresco: ");
    lechuga.imprimirDatos();
    System.out.println("Producto Refrigerado: ");
    jugo.imprimirDatos();

    // Aquí vamos a usar los métodos dameDatos()

    area.append("Proucto Congelado: "+nuggets.dameDatos());
    area.append("Producto Fresco: "+lechuga.dameDatos());
    area.append("Producto Refrigerado: "+jugo.dameDatos());
}
```

Y cambiamos el main de TestHerencia3 para que muestre una pantalla con un botón y muestre los datos en un área:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    //creamos frame o el marco o ventana a mostrar        
    javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    //agregamos esto para terminar ejecución cuando se cierre ventana
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //creamos el botón
    javax.swing.JButton boton = new javax.swing.JButton("dame datos"); 
    //creamos el componente área donde se mostrará info
    final javax.swing.JTextArea area = new javax.swing.JTextArea(20, 40);
    //creamos el objeto que escuchará al botón
    java.awt.event.ActionListener listener = new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //cuando se pique el botón queremos mostrar datos
            dameDatos(area);
        }
    };
    boton.addActionListener(listener);
    //creamos un scroll por si los datos no caben en área 
    javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(area);
    //creamos un panel para integrar el boton y área
    javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panel.add(boton);
    panel.add(scroll);
    ///agregamos el panel al frame
    frame.add(panel);
    //empacamos el frame para definir su tamaño en base al panel
    frame.pack();
     //y mostramos la ventana!!!
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Whao, por fin una respuesta util!, pero aun no entiendo del todo, lo que pasa es que yo quiero cuando cliquee en un boton mostrar, la misma información que ya presento con esa clase por consola este en un text area, pero el problema radica en que dicho frontal, esta en otro paquete, y bueno, no se como hacer que todo lo de clase herencia haora este allí.

Comment: Sí es como mencionas, como quedaria el codigo modificado? lo siento soy principiante en esto, sí pudieses ser mas puntual te lo agradeceria, eh tratado inutilmente, pero no encuentro una respuesta clara de como podria lograrlo

Comment: si pones el código del método imprimeDatos() pudiera darte un mejor ejemplo

Comment: Pondre todos los métodos para que los observes

Comment: Al final de cada clase estan los metodos de ImprimeDatos();

Comment: Mi conocimiento aun no es suficiente para realizar aquello por mí mismo, pero sí puedes ayudarme, te estaria muy agradecido, creeme que eh buscado respuestas, pero en ningun lado la encuentro...

Comment: Axwell, ya modifiqué mi respuesta con la info que pusiste. Si algo no te queda claro me avisas. Suerte

Comment: Todo esta muy bien, exepto la parte de la creación del Jframe y el botón dentro de la misma HerenciaTest3. El punto es que mi Jframe debe de estar en otro paquete, diferente al de las clases, y bueno, eso tambien es un requerimiento.

Comment: Estoy seguro que con el código que puse puedes adaptarlo a lo que te están solicitando. Suerte!